# update table where table name and is in select query

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have to update a table where table name and id is the result of select query .

```
 (select article.articleId ,'MUSIC' as type ,createddate FROM MTDDiscussion article where  article.status=2  and article.createdBy=101 order by createdDate ASC limit 1) UNION (select article.articleId, 'SPORTS' as type ,createddate  FROM MTDOpinion article where  article.status=2  and article.createdBy=101 order by createdDate ASC limit 1)UNION  (select article.articleId ,'DANCE' as type  ,createddate FROM MTDSurvey article where  article.status=2  and article.createdBy=101 order by createdDate ASC limit 1) UNION  (select article.wikiTopicId as articleId ,'SINGING' as type ,createddate  FROM WikiTopic article where  article.status=2  and article.createdBy=101 order by createdDate ASC limit 1) order by 3 ASC limit 1
```

having output

```
 articleid  type        createddate
    1       MUSIC  2017-04-28 12:53:55.649
```

now have to update satus of `MUSIC table  where id =1`

Comment: nothing is clear..what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Avi have to update table where table name is MUSIC and id =1 which came from select query have written.

Comment: you need to use dynamic query for this.

Comment: how do use dynamic query

Comment: You probably need to redesign your schema if you find you need to do this. Using dynamic SQL is not the preferred approach for forming relations in the database.

Comment: Format your code properly. If you did it, ping me and I will remove my downvote.

Answer (score -1):

Get table name,id and status value into some variable and then use below query.

```
  UPDATE_QUERY:='UPDATE '||V_TABLE||
' SET STATUS='||''''||V_STATUS||''''||
' WHERE ID ='''||V_ID||'''';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE UPDATE_QUERY;
    COMMIT;
```